# How to trigger 50v solenoid with 120v AC

Tags: analog, relay, solenoid

I have an old clock with an analog circuit and the timing sync mechanism gets triggered by a solenoid that likely requires 40-50v. The only power input into the circuit is 120v AC.

Ideally I'd like to trigger the solenoid from a microcontroller, but how could this be accomplished without a gigantic transformer?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: You don't need a huge transformer, just one large enough for the wattage you will be drawing. Since it's inside a machine, you can use RU Recognized parts, you don't need UL Listed.

Answer (score 1):

The clock you show is a simplex synchronization clock.
The clutch is driven by pulsating DC and activated when the clock is in sync mode (turns fast to a fixed endpoint).
The 'valve' shown in the schematic is a Thyratron ....this is very like an SCR, but has a high on voltage typically in the 60-90V range. 
When the input sync signal is present (typically 3-4kHz) then the Thyratron is triggered, pulls in the clutch and the clock speeds up till it reaches the sync time.

To replace the circuit you could use an MCU to receive the sync signal and trigger something like a MOC3020 on only the positive part of the AC cycle. Since you would have a full half cycle aplied to the solenoid you should put a series resistor about the same value as the clutch resistance in series.

Comment: I'd like to avoid generating the sync signal (I don't have a master) and instead trigger the solenoid directly from an MCU (the vacuum tube/valve is missing and would need to be replaced)

Comment: The clock should run without the sync signal or the receiver. If the clock does not run it is NOT because of the lack of the sync signal.

Comment: Clock runs fine, but I wanted to be able to sync it in the event of a power outage for example, rather than having to go through some crazy manual process

Comment: Then simply design your MCU to trigger the MOC3020 for the required time on each powerup.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the solenoid is a DC solenoid

If so, rectify the mains, that gets you about 170V DC, then you would use a mosfet or transistor to PWM that solenoid at about 10% time on, to switch it on, this will keep the power the solenoid dissipates similar to its original rating

Comment: I've added a photo of the circuit diagram to the original post. The clutch magnet is the solenoid. Nothing suggests to me that it's DC

Comment: The 5823 is a cold cathode trigger tube, and apparently acts as a rectifier, so the coil will be driven by DC pulses.

Comment: @PeterBennett Okay - thank you for that explanation!